# Problema com transferencia de arquivo via socket com java

Tags: java, arquivo, thread, socket, stream-de-arquivos

Eu estou tentando fazer um programa cliente/servidor que aceite mais de um cliente e esse cliente envia arquivos para o servidor.
A transferência estava funcionando corretamente, porém quando eu coloquei um while para que ao enviar uma vez ele possa dar a opção de enviar outra vez ou sair, acabou dando erro no recebimento do arquivo. Não estou conseguindo resolver esse problema, alguém poderia me ajudar?
A baixo estou enviando o código completo com a saída que eu pus para testar quanto estava sendo lido do arquivo na maquina do cliente e recebido pelo servidor. E não sei se é necessário, mas o arquivo que estou enviando possui 212.594 bytes e a minha IDE é a eclipse.

Cliente:

```
public class AplicaçãoCliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("informe ip:");

        String ip = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("informe porta:");

        int porta = scan.nextInt();

        Socket socket = new Socket(ip, porta);

        System.out.println("O cliente se conectou ao servidor!");

        new Cliente(socket).conectar();

        System.out.println("fim da execução");
    }
}


public class Cliente {

    private Socket cliente;
    private PrintStream saida;
    private Scanner teclado;

    public Cliente(Socket cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;

    }

    public void conectar() throws IOException{

        teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        saida = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
        String continuar = "s";

        System.out.println("------------------BEM-VINDO AO SERVIDOR------------------");
        System.out.println();

        while(continuar.equals("s")){//while adicionado que fez dar o erro

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Digite comando:");



            String comando = teclado.nextLine();


            saida.println(comando);

            if(comando.equals("upload")){

                enviarArquivo("/home/felipe/document.pdf");
            }else if(comando.equals("sair")){
                continuar = "n";
            }else{
                System.out.println("comando não existente");
            }
        }
        cliente.close();
    }

    private void enviarArquivo(String caminho) throws IOException{

        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(caminho);//caminho do arquivo que sera enviado

        OutputStream out = cliente.getOutputStream();

        int tam = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[tam];
        int lidos = 0;
        int i = 0;

        lidos = fileIn.read(buffer, 0, tam);
        System.out.println(i++ + " - lidos: " + lidos);
        while (lidos > 0) {

            out.write(buffer, 0, lidos);
            lidos = fileIn.read(buffer, 0, tam);
            System.out.println(i++ + " - lidos: " + lidos);
        }

        out.flush();
        fileIn.close();

        System.out.println("enviado com sucesso");

    }
}
```

O Servidor:

```
public class AplicaçãoServidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        // inicia o servidor
        Servidor servidor = new Servidor(12345);

        servidor.executa();

        System.out.println("fim");
    }
}

public class Servidor {

    private int porta;

    private ServerSocket servidor;

    public Servidor(int porta) {

        this.porta = porta;

    }

    public void executa() throws IOException {


        Socket cliente;
        servidor = new ServerSocket(this.porta);

        System.out.println("Porta 12345 aberta!");

        while(true){

            // aceita um cliente

            cliente = servidor.accept();

            System.out.println("Nova conexão com o cliente " +

            cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());



            // cria tratador de cliente numa nova thread

            ThreadServidor thread = new ThreadServidor(cliente);

            new Thread(thread).start();



        }
    }

}

public class ThreadServidor implements Runnable {

    private Socket cliente;

    private Scanner entrada;


        public ThreadServidor(Socket cliente) {

        this.cliente = cliente;


    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            entrada = new Scanner(this.cliente.getInputStream());
            String continuar = "s";

            while(continuar.equals("s")){// while adicionado que originou o erro

                String resposta = entrada.nextLine();

                if(resposta.equals("upload")){
                    receberArquivo("/home/felipe/Downloads/documento.pdf");
                }else if(resposta.equals("sair")){
                    continuar = "n";
                }else{
                    System.out.println("comando não existente");
                }
            }
            cliente.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void receberArquivo(String caminho) throws IOException {

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(caminho);// o caminho onde o arquivo sera escrito

        int tam = 4096;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[tam];
        int lidos = 0;

        InputStream in = cliente.getInputStream();

        int i = 0;


        lidos = in.read(buffer, 0, tam);
        System.out.println(i++ + " - lidos: " + lidos);

        while (lidos > 0) {

            fos.write(buffer, 0, lidos);
            lidos = in.read(buffer, 0, tam);
            System.out.println(i++ + " - lidos: " + lidos);
        }

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

        System.out.println("arquivo recebido");


    }


}
```

A saída do Cliente:

```
0 - lidos: 4096
1 - lidos: 4096
2 - lidos: 4096
3 - lidos: 4096
4 - lidos: 4096
5 - lidos: 4096
6 - lidos: 4096
7 - lidos: 4096
8 - lidos: 4096
9 - lidos: 4096
10 - lidos: 4096
11 - lidos: 4096
12 - lidos: 4096
13 - lidos: 4096
14 - lidos: 4096
15 - lidos: 4096
16 - lidos: 4096
17 - lidos: 4096
18 - lidos: 4096
19 - lidos: 4096
20 - lidos: 4096
21 - lidos: 4096
22 - lidos: 4096
23 - lidos: 4096
24 - lidos: 4096
25 - lidos: 4096
26 - lidos: 4096
27 - lidos: 4096
28 - lidos: 4096
29 - lidos: 4096
30 - lidos: 4096
31 - lidos: 4096
32 - lidos: 4096
33 - lidos: 4096
34 - lidos: 4096
35 - lidos: 4096
36 - lidos: 4096
37 - lidos: 4096
38 - lidos: 4096
39 - lidos: 4096
40 - lidos: 4096
41 - lidos: 4096
42 - lidos: 4096
43 - lidos: 4096
44 - lidos: 4096
45 - lidos: 4096
46 - lidos: 4096
47 - lidos: 4096
48 - lidos: 4096
49 - lidos: 4096
50 - lidos: 4096
51 - lidos: 3698
52 - lidos: -1
enviado com sucesso
```

A saída do Servidor

```
0 - lidos: 4096
1 - lidos: 4096
2 - lidos: 4096
3 - lidos: 4096
4 - lidos: 4096
5 - lidos: 4096
6 - lidos: 4096
7 - lidos: 4096
8 - lidos: 4096
9 - lidos: 4096
10 - lidos: 4096
11 - lidos: 4096
12 - lidos: 4096
13 - lidos: 4096
14 - lidos: 4096
15 - lidos: 4096
16 - lidos: 4096
17 - lidos: 4096
18 - lidos: 4096
19 - lidos: 4096
20 - lidos: 4096
21 - lidos: 4096
22 - lidos: 4096
23 - lidos: 4096
24 - lidos: 4096
25 - lidos: 4096
26 - lidos: 4096
27 - lidos: 4096
28 - lidos: 4096
29 - lidos: 4096
30 - lidos: 4096
31 - lidos: 4096
32 - lidos: 4096
33 - lidos: 4096
34 - lidos: 4096
35 - lidos: 4096
36 - lidos: 4096
37 - lidos: 4096
38 - lidos: 4096
39 - lidos: 4096
40 - lidos: 4096
41 - lidos: 4096
42 - lidos: 4096
43 - lidos: 4096
44 - lidos: 4096
45 - lidos: 4096
46 - lidos: 4096
47 - lidos: 4096
48 - lidos: 4096
49 - lidos: 4096
50 - lidos: 4096
51 - lidos: 3698
```

Ele não saiu do while. Ele não recebeu o -1 que estava recebendo antes para avisar fim do arquivo. E dessa forma não imprimiu na tela que o recebimento foi sucesso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui chegar a uma solução, mudei apenas o metodo de enviarArquivo e receberArquivo e antes do metodo de enviar o arquivo eu pus um Thread.sleep(200). Acredito que possa ser menos de 200, mas não testei.

O codigo de receberArquivo foi mudado para ficar assim:

public void receiveFile(String caminho) throws IOException {

```
        try {

        int bytesRead;
        DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(
                cliente.getInputStream());

        String fileName = clientData.readUTF();
        String caminhoCompleto = caminho + "/" + fileName;

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream((caminhoCompleto));
        long size = clientData.readLong();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        while (size > 0
                && (bytesRead = clientData.read(buffer, 0,
                        (int) Math.min(buffer.length, size))) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            size -= bytesRead;
        }

        output.close();

        System.out.println("Arquivo " + fileName
                + " recebido pelo cliente.");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Arquivo não encontrado");
    }

}
```

O codigo de enviarArquivo foi mudado para

public void sendFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

```
        try {

        File myFile = new File(fileName);
        byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);


        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
        dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);


        OutputStream os = cliente.getOutputStream();


        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
        dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
        dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
        dos.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
        dos.flush();

        System.out.println("Arquivo "+fileName+" enviado para cliente.");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Arquivo não existe!");
    } 
}
```

Com isso minha conclusão foi que o erro estava no sincronismo dos métodos,ao colocar o Thread.sleep() o código espera até que as funções sendo executadas acima pare por tempo suficiente para o método que recebe o arquivo fique travado no método de ler os bytes, assim eu não enviarei o arquivo até que o método que o recebe esteja pronto para tal.